# Update Linux Mint 19.0 Tessa

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

When I try to update Linux Mint 19.1 in the terminal using `sudo-apt update`, 
I get an error message like this:

> WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

Comment: Is there anything else checking for updates, such as the default program that checks every time you log in, or is Synaptic open, or any update configuration tool?

Comment: What command did you run, exactly?

Comment: Are you updating from 19.0 to 19.1? Your subject line says you want to update 19.0, but the first sentence of the body text says 19.1. Please click [edit] and revise your question and/or subject line.

Answer (score 0):

Stay with 19.0 since they both have the same exact support. You might have a package loaded that is not compatible actually like Brave?